# Win8 C# trouble with async/await

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, c#-5.0

Why in the second case the exception is thrown?

```
async void f() {
    await media.InitializeAsync();
    isInit = true;
    capturePreview.Source = media;
    await media.StartPreviewAsync(); // Ok
}

// ------------------------------------------

void f() {
    StaticClass.g(capturePreview.Source);
}

public static class StaticClass {
    public static async void g(MediaSource source) {
        await media.InitializeAsync();
        isInit = true;
        source = media;
        await media.StartPreviewAsync(); // Unknown Exception (It's seems that media isn't init)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your source code here as well (Links go away over time but if you add your code it will live on for future generations to look at in awe).

Comment: Are you running these methods on them main UI thread?

Comment: Hmm.. yes.. I'm running them from protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) in MainPage.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

The `f()` function use a function which include `async`.
So I think the `f()` should be signed `async` as well.
Like this: `void async f(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want media to be initialized, why don't you do the rest of the code in the .done function ?

```
 void f() {
     StaticClass.g(capturePreview.Source);
    }

  public static class StaticClass {
     public static async void g(MediaSource source) {
       media.InitializeAsync().done(
       isInit = true;
       source = media;
       await media.StartPreviewAsync(););
     }
  }
```

Even if I'm not fully sure you can do an async within a done callback.

Comment: Sorry about that I made a mistake while  reading the doc.
 Did you try staying in the same thread instead of going back to the UI thread after media.InitializeAsync. 
Try this to your initial code : await media.InitializeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);  Maybe it can solve the case

Comment: But there isn't ConfigureAwait (media - MediaCapture)

Comment: And can you do : 
await media.InitializeAsync().ToTask().ConfigureAwait(false);